# pyenv and installing certain Python packages

Tags: python, cython, pyenv

I'm trying to install an older version of Python on my Mac. I'm currently running 2.7.9, but our production environment is running 2.7.6. (There is a compatibility issue with gevent and 2.7.9.)

I found [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) which allows me to install various versions. I've installed pyenv with brew and installed 2.7.6. I then created a virtualenv with 2.7.6 with the following command:

```
mkvirtualenv my_env --python=/Users/dustin/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/python
```

It seems to work fine and I'm running Python 2.7.6. The problem I am running into is that I can't install certain packages with pip such as Cython or M2crypto. I get C compile errors.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

If I create a virtualenv without specifying the Python version, these packages install fine. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to trying to run an older version of Python 2.7.x (like 2.7.6) on newer releases of OS X.  If you are on OS X 10.10, that's very likely the problem.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue21811.  You may need to add at least the patch for `_osx_support.py`.  If not, try running `pip` with `-v` and update your question with the results.

Update: With the additional information you supplied, it is clear that you are running into the OS X 10.10 support issues that were fixed in the changes for Issue21811 released in 2.7.8.  In particular, the `configure` changes are needed to correctly parse the two-digit minor version number (`10`); otherwise, the code in `configure` mistakenly thinks you are are running on a very old version of OS X and generates obsolete link directives.  You should backport https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/2672e30d9095 and https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/a7ab09e00dbc.

Comment: Here is the verbose log trying to install cython: http://pastebin.com/bQyMP9Tr

Curious why it is trying to use `python.exe`